# Cassandra materialized view not in sync with base table

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I am running into a strange problem where 1 out of 4 materialized view on base table is out of sync on all nodes.

I have tried below options but still not able to make out any solution.

1. nodetool refresh on all nodes
2. nodetool repair on keyspace
3. Also, I ran nodetool compaction to clear tombstones.

Finally, I dropped and recreated the materialized view and as the data is huge the view is stuck in build process. I can view the build process in opCenter and in system.views_builds_in_progress table.

Then I manually stopped the build process with nodetool stop VIEW_BUILD and ran the compaction again. Still the issue persists.

Is it because one of the primary key of my materialized view is having primary key for which about 60% of data in base table is NULL?

i.e I have primary key of materialized as (key1, key2, key3) for key1 there will be about 60% of data in base table as null.